# Concurrency in SaveChanges in EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand how the `SaveChanges` method works in EF Core in the context of ASP.NET Core web application. What happens if two users are performing the same operation on the same table and it leads to them both executing `SaveChanges`? Does it mean that `SaveChanges` will use some kind of lock or queue internally and execute the first statement, and then another in sequence, even if `SaveChanges` is called at the same time by two users executing the same action method?

I mean, for example, using `ExecuteSqlCommand` to execute insert with the nested select statement in raw SQL statement, and then calling `SaveChanges`. Does anything in `SaveChanges` behavior change if there is more than one operation before calling it?

Comment: Each instance of your context is separated completely from other instances. SaveChanges will simply check for changes in current instance and generate sql to write back these changes. You can add concurrency checks as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency

Comment: EF core implements *optimistic concurrency control*, meaning it will let multiple users make changes independently without the overhead of synchronization or locking. In an ideal situation, these changes will not interfere with each other and therefore succeed. In the worst case scenario, two or more users will try to make conflicting changes, and only one of them should succeed.